# Flutter inspector not working properly in windows 11

Tags: flutter

Frequently i am using flutter inspector for debugging purpose but after installing windows 11 update . when i start debugging with inspector than it only shows me widget tree and not showing the code line where its been used .
here are i am sharing version of flutter and android studio
Flutter SDK: 3.7.10 & Android Studio : Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Lastly i am sharing the screen short  of issue .[screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYnXp.png)

I have tried all the possible way as an reinstalling studio by erasing all files from everywhere and also try to update latest flutter sdk version also . But not work anything. Please help to solve this issue if anyone have solution for that.